Consistent alignment of tabular in an IEEE document class
The following table in an IEEE document class does not look very consistent to me. I appreciate any recommendations or ideas you share for improvement.

This is how to reproduce the table. Thanks for your comments.
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} % Use the IEEE conference class

% Required packages
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{KPI Achievement Levels for Various Metrics}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xllr@{}} 
\toprule
Metric                          & As-Is Model        & To-Be Model        & Improve- \\
                                &                    &                    & ment     \\ 
\midrule
Total resource costs            & SAR 86,694.98      & SAR 49,586.26      & 42.8\%   \\
Process Sigma level             & 2.3                & 4.1                & 78.3\%   \\
Data entry errors               & Baseline           & 98.2\% reduction   & 98.2\%   \\
Unauthorized access prevention  & Baseline           & 99.7\% improvement & 99.7\%   \\
Average processing time         & 25 minutes         & 2 minutes          & 92\%     \\
Process variation               & High variation     & 92\% reduction     & 92\%     \\
Student satisfaction            & Baseline           & 90\% positive      & 90\%     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab7}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}


This question seems to solicit opinion-based answers. Can you provide some specifics as to what the problems are you're facing and the suggested solution you're looking for? Currently "not ... very consistent" is subjective.

Just out of idle curiosity: What is "SAR" -- the code for a currency? Depending on what it is, there may be a need to format the associated number in a particular way.

@Mico - Yes, SAR is a currency, and thanks for your valuable recommendations below.

There's not much that's wrong with your table as is. I have only a few suggestions:

Don't use a center environment in a table environment. instead, use a `\centering directive.

Load a Times Roman math font package, such as newtxmath, to go along with the Times Roman text font.

The caption package doesn't play well with the IEEEtran document class. Just use the default caption formatting of the class.

Add hanging indentation to the first column's properties.

Simplify the final column by moving the % symbol into the header and by aligning the numbers on their decimal markers.

Purely aesthetic: Place the \label instruction right after the \caption instruction instead of toward the very end of the table environment.



\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} % Use the IEEE conference class
\usepackage{newtxmath} % Times Roman math font package

% Required packages
\usepackage{tabularx} 
%\usepackage{array}   % is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'  
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
%\usepackage{caption} % don't use this package the 'IEEEtran' document class
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{KPI achievement levels for various metrics}
\label{tab7}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}
     >{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X
     l
     l
     S[table-format=2.1] @{}} 
\toprule
Metric & As-Is Model  & To-Be Model  & {Improve-}  \\
       &              &              & {ment (\%)} \\ 
\midrule
Total resource costs            & SAR 86,694.98  & SAR 49,586.26      & 42.8 \\
Process Sigma level             & 2.3            & 4.1                & 78.3 \\
Data entry errors               & Baseline       & 98.2\% reduction   & 98.2 \\
Unauthorized access prevention  & Baseline       & 99.7\% improvement & 99.7 \\
Average processing time         & 25 minutes     & 2 minutes          & 92   \\
Process variation               & High variation & 92\% reduction     & 92   \\
Student satisfaction            & Baseline       & 90\% positive      & 90   \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}

